# Unix server: how many established connections are normal?

Tags: mysql, unix, server, netstat

I'm having issue with a prestashop site I have hosted on a Digitalocean: mysql is consuming most of the CPU and Memory even when Google Analytics is telling that there were 20 visits on the last 30 minutes… so looking around I did a `netstat -na` and saw that there's around 300 connections from Foreign Address, half of them `ESTABLISHED`, and around 200 Active domain sockets, and bunch of them are from China… Is this normal? They seems weird to me compared to the actual visits, but I have never used netstat before (I did it cause I read about it on some SO threads) so I don't know how to read it ‍♂️

If they are not normal, what could I do about them?

Thanks!

Comment: When you used netstat, were you counting all connections or just HTTP connections? There are probably lots of hackers trying to break into your server.

Comment: I'm count all connections, but most of them are HTTP. And most sockets are `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, when mysql is only open for localhost.
I've just upgrade the server to the double of CPU and Memore (2 cores and 4GB of ram) and everything is up to 100% again, with just 5 visits…

Comment: GA uses JavaScript and cookies to track visits. Web crawlers and hackers don't execute JS, they won't be counted.

Comment: I know, but how do I know if the hackers are trying to get in or if they are already in?

Comment: That's what logfiles are for. You'll get better help on [sf] and [security.se]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Make sure your landing page does not have queries to the database, or very little.  If you expect a lot of traffic you could cache some query results, if you expect them to be always the same result.  Ex. do not store your web page text in the database.  You can also reduce the MySQL connection timeout so unused connections are removed faster.  Use connection pooling to avoid having 1 query == 1 connection.  TIME_WAIT, CLOSE_WAIT, CLOSE_WAIT2 are not a problem, ESTABLISHED are.  The other states are TCPIP stack cleanup.  There is a setting for that at the OS level.

Comment: What is the response from MySQL Command Prompt to SELECT @@max_connect_errors;  this value is one of your defensive parameters.  10 would be recommended in your my.cnf or my.ini